# Mautic Cannot Fetch the Replied email after Email servicer(IMAP and SMTP) is changed

Tags: email, mautic

Mautic version is: 4.1.0

My PHP version is:7.4

My Database type and version is: Mariadb 10.5

How should email be handled?–>Immediately

Default Frequency Rule–>Do not send me more than–>20 per day.

Cron Job

/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/mauticcrons.sh
Script below
GNU nano 2.9.3 /usr/local/bin/mauticcrons.sh

```
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:segment:update --batch-limit=900
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:campaigns:trigger --campaign-limit=2
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:import --limit=500
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:webhooks:process
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:reports:scheduler
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:email:fetch
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:maintenance:cleanup –days-old=365
```

else
php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:broadcasts:send --limit=3

php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:emails:send --message-limit=200

php $MAUTICCONSOLE mautic:email:fetch

fi

Your problem

My problem is:

Since I have changed the Email Server(IMAP and SMTP) to the new one but keep the same email address.

My email replied but Mautic did not find it. It should show “Email replied” on a new row.

Anyone can fix this? I can pay and it is no problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbjN9.png)

These errors are showing in the log: No Error on the mautic

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to double check that you did add your reply address in the email config and did also add the folder which mautic should track in the configuration under "email settings" in the section "monitored inbox settings".

Explanation:

Mautic is only able to fetch emails and check for replies/bounces/complaints, if it knows the inbox which should be checked. Therefore you need to connect the inbox in the configuration menu under "email settings" inside the "monitored inbox settings"

Comment: Please explain why that helps.

Comment: Mautic is only able to fetch emails and check for replies/bounces/complaints, if it knows the inbox which should be checked. Therefore you need to connect the inbox in the configuration menu under "email settings" inside the "monitored inbox settings"

Comment: Please [edit] to add the explanation to the answer.